# How do I complete an OR operation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, or-operator

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (!$('body').hasClass('home') || !$('ul#main-menu li.wwd').hasClass('active')){
$("ul#sub-menu").css('display','none');
$(".main-content").css('margin-top','13px');
$("ul#sub-menu").mouseover(function() {
        $("ul#sub-menu").show();
        $(".main-content").css('margin-top','62px');

}).mouseout(function() {
        $("ul#sub-menu").hide();
        $(".main-content").css('margin-top','13px');
});
$("li.wwd").mouseover(function() {
        $("ul#sub-menu").show();
        $(".main-content").css('margin-top','62px');
}).mouseout(function() {
        $("ul#sub-menu").hide();
        $(".main-content").css('margin-top','13px');
});
}
if ($('ul#main-menu li.wwd').is('.active')){
        $(".main-content").css('margin-top','62px');

}
})
```

I need to run this jQuery on all pages besides the home page(that works fine) but also not on pages where `li.wwd` has class `active`.  I thought this would work with an OR operation but it does not.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem and what you're asking.

Comment: Is this code working? or not?

Comment: To evaluate the not condition for both places you need to use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: In the 2nd line of code I am trying to do an OR `||` conditional.  It is not working.

Comment: Thanks @SheikhHeera!  That was it.  Apprently I needed an AND `&&` operator instead of `||`.  I thought that and AND operator meant that both conditions had to be true.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To evaluate the `!(not)` condition for both places you need to use `&&` instead of `||`, just like

```
if (!$('body').hasClass('home') && !$('ul#main-menu li.wwd').hasClass('active'))
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the negation operator (!) your block of code is currently running when either of these scenarios are true:

1. body does **NOT** have the class "home" OR
2. ul#main-menu li.wwd does **NOT** have the class "active"

So I suspect your home page code appears to be working fine because on that page, the ul#main-menu li.wwd might not have the class "active"?